# Average SharePoint fields with Yes as it's value

Tags: sharepoint

Here is the formula I'm trying to use, but it's always resulting in zeros.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
=(IF([In AD]="Yes",1,0)+IF([In Auvik]="Yes",1,0)+IF([In LANSweeper]="Yes",1,0)+IF([In Sophos]="Yes",1,0)+IF([In VSA]="Yes",1,0))/5
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct, but I think the problem occurs in your reference to the field names.  I notice that all your field names have spaces in them.  Spaces = bad when it comes to SharePoint.  Most likely what happened is that SharePoint assigned the field name behind the scenes to be "In%20AD" instead of "In AD" etc.
Try substituting the spaces in your field name references of the formula with %20 instead i.e.

`=(IF([In%20AD]="Yes",1,0) +IF([In%20Auvik]="Yes",1,0) +IF([In%20LANSweeper]="Yes",1,0) +IF([In%20Sophos]="Yes",1,0) +IF([In%20VSA]="Yes",1,0))/5`